# Can bsxfun be substituted for faster operation?

Tags: matlab, optimization, bsxfun

I have thousand calling in this line of code

```
idx=sub2ind(size(I),x,y);
A=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, a, d),I(idx));
B=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, b, d),I(idx));
C=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, b, c),I(idx));
D=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, a, c),I(idx));
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d =1xn` matrix, and `I=mxn` matrix (can be up to 1920x1080). For example:

```
x=10; y=40;
a=rand(1,100);
b=rand(1,100);
c=rand(1,100);
d=rand(1,100);
I=rand(500,500);
```

Vectorized method would be using `.*`, however after several tests, `.*` is halves **SLOWER** than `bsxfun` (I'm using MATLAB 2017a).

Any other suggestion to improve this? I'm asking for CPU computation though, not GPU. A slight improvement percentage is very significant as for a week time's computation. Thanks!

Fact: Those line of codes were compiled into MEX and called 40855882 times, with total/self time of 19558.370 seconds. That's not even 10% of total computation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.*`. I know you said it's slower but on my computer (and 2016b) it's about 70 times faster...

```
x=10; y=40;
a=rand(1,100);
b=rand(1,100);
c=rand(1,100);
d=rand(1,100);
I=rand(500,500);
idx=sub2ind(size(I),x,y);
n = 10000;
tic
for ii = 1:n % vectorized version
    A1 = a.*d*I(idx);
    B1 = b.*d*I(idx);
    C1 = b.*c*I(idx);
    D1 = a.*c*I(idx);
end
t1 = toc;
tic
for ii = 1:n % bsxfun version
    A=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, a, d),I(idx));
    B=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, b, d),I(idx));
    C=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, b, c),I(idx));
    D=bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@times, a, c),I(idx));
end    
t = toc;
t/t1
```